# Installing Rubber for proper Launch of instance creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubber

I am trying to launch an Amazon EC2 instance using Rubber.

```
cap rubber:create_staging
```

rubber-ruby.yml reflects a version in use

```
ruby_build_version: 20141027
ruby_version: 1.9.3-p550
```

However upon `cap rubber:create_staging` capistrano immediately aborts with

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rubber
/Users/you/r/rubbertest/Capfile:14:in `require'
```

with the capfile stating

```
$:.unshift "#{root}/vendor/plugins/rubber/lib/"  # line 13
require 'rubber'                                 # line 14
```

So I assumed a rubber gem would be necessary.  The gem file edited (without capistrano the process failed early)

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'rubber'
```

And the process went one step further to another failure:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
/Users/you/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rubber-1.15.0/lib/rubber/capistrano.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/you/r/rubbertest/Capfile:17:in `require'
```

the capistrano.rb file is a one liner

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance.load(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'recipes', 'rubber.rb'))
```

being called by the capfile

```
Rubber::initialize(root, env)
require 'rubber/capistrano'   # line 17
```

Another oddity is that the final instruction of the Capfile calls

```
Dir['vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
```

and that directory is empty which is consistent with the instructions : [Rubber can be installed as a rubygem (recommended)](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/wiki/Installation)

I have run this twice with identical behaviour.

However these gaps (no reference to rubber gem, nor capistrano, calling vendor/plugins against gemmification preference) tell me that some step is missing here.  where has this gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that gem identity matters :

```
#  gem 'rubber'
```

would only install version 1.15.0, By specifying

```
gem 'rubber', '3.1.0'
```

then `cap rubber:config` runs.  create_staging will start running as well.
*note* the version is an issue: the one originally posted was somehow requiring a separate capistrano entry and  leading to a later failure. The [list of versions is here](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubber/versions)